# How to read the entire file into a list in python?

Tags: python

I want to read an entire file into a python list any one knows how to?

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Comment: Have you read _any_ of the Python documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print "\nReading the entire file into a list."
text_file = open("read_it.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
print lines
print len(lines)
for line in lines:
    print line
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Actually there is no need to iterate twice here - first using readlines and second using for loop

Answer (score 9):

Simpler:

```
with open(path) as f:
    myList = list(f)
```

If you don't want linebreaks, you can do `list(f.read().splitlines())`

Answer (score 4):

[Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755229/max)'s answer will work, but you'll be left with the `endline` character (`\n`) at the end of each line.

Unless that's desirable behavior, use the following paradigm:

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    print line # Won't have '\n' at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
allRows = [] # in case you need to store it
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        # do something with row
        # And / Or
        allRows.append(row)
```

Note that you don't need to care here about closing file, and also there is no need to use readlines here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Python3's `pathlib` allows you to safely read the entire file in one line without writing the `with open(...)` statement, using the [read_text method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) - it will open the file, read the contents and close the file for you:

```
lines = Path(path_to_file).read_text().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, slightly different:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip())
```